# How do I add export CLI='docker run -it --entrypoint cardano-cli -e NETWORK=testnet ...' so I can run CLI on Mac OS Monterey zshrc

Tags: macos, docker, zsh, docker-compose, macos-monterey

I have tried adding the following

```
     export CLI='docker run -it --entrypoint cardano-cli -e NETWORK=testnet -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket -v cardano-node-ipc-testnet:/ipc inputoutput/cardano-node'

deano@Ds-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo vi ~/.zshrc 
deano@Ds-MacBook-Pro ~ % source  ~/.zshrc 
deano@Ds-MacBook-Pro ~ % CLI
zsh: command not found: CLI
```

How do I add CLI as a command for custom docker run -it

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias

```
sudo vi ~/.zshrc 
alias CLI="docker run -it --entrypoint cardano-cli -e NETWORK=testnet -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket -v cardano-node-ipc-testnet:/ipc inputoutput/cardano-node"
source  ~/.zshrc
```